# Firebase Phone Auth with React Native does not accept certain real numbers

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native, react-native-firebase

I seem to have broken something in the Firebase Phone Auth. I am using my own backend system and Firebase with React Native only for Phone Auth and FCM.

The background is that I had an old project which I was using for auth. Later there had to be another app, so instead of having multiple apps under the same project, I created two new projects for each of the apps. Then I removed all apps from the old project.

Now when I use the real phone numbers which were used with the old project, they no longer seem to work. Test numbers set up under the new projects are all fine.

I can't afford to "waste" any more real numbers in case they become unusable too for further testing.

Using the React Native Firebase module, it looks something like:

```
auth()
    .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
    .then(confirmation => {
      dispatch({
        type: PHONENUMBER_SIGNIN_SUBMIT_SUCCESS,
        payload: confirmation,
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('received  error from firebase auth', JSON.stringify(error));
      dispatch({
        type: PHONENUMBER_SIGNIN_SUBMIT_FAIL,
        payload: error,
      });
    });
```

With the phone numbers which were used with the old project, it ends up in the catch block, with a cryptic error message `{"line":7186,"column":64,"sourceURL":"http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.xxx.yyy&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true"}`

This line 7186 is in a code block that looks like this

```
   7172     module.exports = _wrapNativeSuper = function _wrapNativeSuper(Class) {
   7173       if (Class === null || !_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[0], "./isNativeFunction.js")(Class)) return Class;
   7174 
   7175       if (typeof Class !== "function") {
   7176         throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function");
   7177       }
   7178 
   7179       if (typeof _cache !== "undefined") {
   7180         if (_cache.has(Class)) return _cache.get(Class);
   7181 
   7182         _cache.set(Class, Wrapper);
   7183       }
   7184 
   7185       function Wrapper() {
   7186         return _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[1], "./construct.js")(Class, arguments, _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[2], "./getPrototypeOf.js")(this).constructor);
   7187       }
   7188 
   7189       Wrapper.prototype = Object.create(Class.prototype, {
   7190         constructor: {
   7191           value: Wrapper,
   7192           enumerable: false,
   7193           writable: true,
   7194           configurable: true
   7195         }
   7196       });
   7197       return _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[3], "./setPrototypeOf.js")(Wrapper, Class);
   7198     };
```

Since I have no clue what could be causing this problem, any help and solution approach will be very appreciated.

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen I am glad this question has caught the attention of staff members. If you need any more details just let me know, or the project IDs if you need them. I should clarify that the all this is in debug mode (via USB), the apps are not live yet (will be soon).  I might have made matters worse by deleting and then undeleting (2x) the old project in a futile attempt to resolve the issue.

Comment: UPDATE - Sometime after posting here, I added the numbers in question as test numbers in the auth console. And then removed one of them from test numbers a few hours later, And it started working normally again - I get the OTP for it (I did not yet check the others). Smarter people than I might be able to better guess what happened underneath.